# Adding title attribute to an image in rst

Tags: restructuredtext, pelican

Seems like restructured text markup is very limited when it comes to image options:

> The following options are recognized:
>   alt : text
>   height : length
>   width : length or percentage of the current line width
>   scale : integer percentage (the "%" symbol is optional)
>   align : "top", "middle", "bottom", "left", "center", or "right"
>   target : text (URI or reference name)

Is it possible to set some custom attributes like title via reStructuredText markup?

e.g.

```
.. image:: foobar.jpg 
    :title: mouse over text, hi!
```

Would output:

```
<img src="foobar.jpg" title="mouse over text, hi!"></img>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can add attribute to img tag in Pelican](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819422/how-i-can-add-attribute-to-img-tag-in-pelican)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image), the following options are recognized: alt, height, width, scale, align, target, class, and name.  No title.

Options include [rewriting in the client with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5567955/2214933) or work with the docutils team to make a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/feature-requests/) and implement it.

Comment: Yes, I pointed this out in my question. Having some javascript to move `alt` attribute to `title` is a great idea though! I'll consider a PR to docutils too :)

Comment: The `alt` attribute isn't really intended to be a caption, the way a title sometimes is, but to describe the image in case it can't be displayed; either because it did not load or for screen readers. e.g. 

`<img src="images/dinosaur.jpg" alt="The head and torso of a dinosaur skeleton; it has a large head with long sharp teeth" title="A T-Rex on display in the Manchester University Museum">`
 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML#image_titles

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`figure`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#figure)

```
.. figure:: picture.png

   This is the caption of the figure.
```

Comment: This results in the caption showing up below the image.  While this can be very useful, it is different from adding a `title` attribute in `<img>` (which makes the text show up when hovering the mouse over the image).

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could simply use [the "raw" directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621042/how-to-embed-html-in-restructured-text-file) and directly use your ideal target html

```
.. raw:: html

    <img src="foobar.jpg" title="mouse over text, hi!"></img>
```